# JavaScript: Find the number in an array which is closest to an given number

Tags: javascript, algorithm, array

It's actually an exercise from an Assembly-course I'm doing:

> Find closest number.
>
> ```
> Add the following into the data section:
>
> nums  dd  23h,75h,111h,0abch,443h,1000h,5h,2213h,433a34h,0deadbeafh
>
> This is an array of numbers. 
>
> Write a program that receives a number x as input, and finds the dword
> inside the array nums, which is the closest to x. (We define the distance
> between two numbers to be the absolute value of the difference: |a-b|).
>
> Example:
>
> For the input of 100h, the result will be 111h, because 111h is closer to
> 100h than any other number in the nums array. (|100h - 111h| = 11h).
> ```

Full exercise-sheet on [GitHub](https://github.com/xorpd/asm_prog_ex/blob/master/4_basic_assembly/3_memory/5_ex/2_write_code/write_code.txt).

Because it's easier for me to develop the algorithm in more familiar JavaScript and because it's a nice exercise I have done it in JavaScript first. Now the only thing left to do is to find an Assembly-specific way.

Anyway: Here's the JavaScript-code I've written to solve the task.

```js
let nums = [ 0x23, 0x75, 0x111,
             0xabc, 0x443, 0x1000,
             0x5, 0x2213, 0x433a34,
             0xdeadbeaf
           ];
let given = 0x100; // { 256 }10

// --- The Relevant Part --------------------------------------
function findIndexClosestNumber(arrayToSearch, compareNumber) {
  'use strict';
  let closest = compareNumber;
  let indexClosest = 0;

  arrayToSearch.forEach((currentNumber, index) => {
    let currentDistance =
      Math.abs(compareNumber - currentNumber);

    if (currentDistance < closest) {
      indexClosest = index;
      closest = currentDistance;
    }
  });

  return indexClosest;
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------

// ------ Testing & Demo ---------------------------------------
console.log(findIndexClosestNumber(nums, given));

nums.length = 0;

for (let i = 0; i <= 90; i += 10) {
  nums.push(i);
}

console.log(nums);

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100));

  console.log('%s gives index %s', randomNumber,
    findIndexClosestNumber(
      nums, randomNumber));
}
```

- Can I expect my implementation to solve the task in a correct way?
- Was it a good idea to initialize the `closest`-variable with the value of the `compareNumber`-parameter?
- Was it a good idea to check for `currentDistance < closest`? Or should I have used `currentDistance <= closest`?

Currently the first occurrence-index is returned in case the number is contained multiple times. Using `<=` it would return the last occurrence-index.

I'm not sure what's the better practice.

Any other comments concerning structure, naming, used methods, algorithm appreciated too.

And if someone knows a cool JavaScript specific way to solve the task: That would interest me too. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your main questions

> - Can I expect my implementation to solve the task in a correct way?

You should know that the answer is "yes" before posting a question on Code Review.

> - Was it a good idea to initialize the 'closest'-variable with the value of the 'compareNumber'-parameter?

No, it's a *mistake*. The function incorrectly returns 0 for input `[10, 9], 3`.
When looking for the minimum distance,
you must choose as the default the largest possible number.
For example if you target ES6, then `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

> - Was it a good idea to check for 'currentDistance < closest'? Or should I have used 'currentDistance <= closest'?

That depends entirely on the specification.
If you're looking for the first closest index, then use `<`.
If the last, then use `>`.

If the specification was not clear,
then ask to clarify.

#### Naming

The names are overly verbose.
When short names are sufficient, they are better than long names.

For example,
in a function to find the closest index to a number,
the array parameter is obviously for searching,
so instead of `arrayToSearch`, it could be simply `nums`,
and `compareNumber` could be `target`.

I would have written like this:

```
function indexOfClosest(nums, target) {
  let closest = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  let index = 0;

  nums.forEach((num, i) => {
    let dist = Math.abs(target - num);

    if (dist < closest) {
      index = i;
      closest = dist;
    }
  });

  return index;
}
```